# issues when managing multiple stacks

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

Investigating a solution to manage multiple stacks, posted the problem and code I am debugging. The question is, why function popAt(int index) shift from bottom of next sub-stack? Does it because of the next element (in the order of stack push) of top of sub-stack 1, is bottom element of sub-stack 2? I am not sure if this behavior is correct, and whether the expected behavior is, after pop element of stack 1, the next element to pop is the element in stack 1 which is under previous top, other than bottom of next stack?

Imagine a (literal) stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it might topple. Therefore, in real life, we would likely start a new stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. A data structure SetOfStacks that mimics this. SetOfStacks should be composed of several stacks, and should create a new stack once the previous one exceeds capacity. SetOfStacks.push() and SetOfStacks.pop() should behave identically to a single stack (that is, pop() should return the same values as it would if there were just a single stack), and function popAt(int index) which performs a pop operation on a specific sub-stack.

```
public class SetOfStacks {
    ArrayList<Stack> stacks = new ArrayList<>();
    public int capacity;
    public SetOfStacks(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public Stack getLastStack() {
        if (stacks.size() == 0) return null;
        return stacks.get(stacks.size() - 1);
    }
    public void push(int v) { /* see earlier code */
    }
    public int pop() {
        Stack last = getLastStack();
        System.out.println(stacks.size());
        int v = last.pop();
        if (last.size == 0) stacks.remove(stacks.size() - 1);
        return v;
    }
    public int popAt(int index) {
        return leftShift(index, true);
    }
    public int leftShift(int index, boolean removeTop) {
        Stack stack = stacks.get(index);
        int removed_item;
        if (removeTop) removed_item = stack.pop();
        else removed_item = stack.removeBottom();
        if (stack.isEmpty()) {
            stacks.remove(index);
        } else if (stacks.size() > index + 1) {
            int v = leftShift(index + 1, false);
            stack.push(v);
        }
        return removed_item;
    }
 }
 public class Stack {
    private int capacity;
    public Node top, bottom;
    public int size = 0;
    public Stack(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public boolean isAtCapacity() {
        return capacity == size;
    }
    public void join(Node above, Node below) {
        if (below != null) below.above = above;
        if (above != null) above.below = below;
    }
    public boolean push(int v) {
        if (size >= capacity) return false;
        size++;
        Node n = new Node(v);
        if (size == 1) bottom = n;
        join(n, top);
        top = n;
        return true;
    }
    public int pop() {
        Node t = top;
        top = top.below;
        size--;
        return t.value;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    public int removeBottom() {
        Node b = bottom;
        bottom = bottom.above;
        if (bottom != null) bottom.below = null;
        size--;
        return b.value;
    }
 }
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to use a debugger.

Comment: @Henry, do you think popAt(int index) behavior is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*leftShift()* in your code may be called recursively with increasing index, that's why if you call it with index of 1 it may pop from stack #2 then (and, in a case when all stacks were 1 element in size, it will continue with stack #3, #4 and so on :( )

Comment: Thanks AndreyS, my confusion is, when we pop from sub-stack 1, and pop again from sub-stack 1, the expected element to be popped out is the 2nd top element of sub-stack 1, but if we shift from bottom of 2nd sub-stack, if we pop then pop again, it will be the bottom element of 2nd sub-stack. I am not sure how do you think, which behavior is correct?

Comment: It's not clear for me what is the intended use of getAt. If your container's purpose is solely to split the big stack into a set of small stacks for the sake of storage optimization, which is the reason to let user access to the top element of i-th substack?  As for getAt behavior,it seems correct (as far as I understand without testing it). If you take a 'plate' from a stack, all substacks to the right should be shifted to keep their 'standard' size (except for the rightmost substack that will get shorter)

Comment: Thanks AndreyS, if so, why shift from bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple solution of stacks of plate using linkedList in java.

```
class Stack<T>{
Node top;
NodeTop nodeTop;
int count = 1;
int i = 3;
static class Node<T>{
    private T data;
    private Node next;
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}

static class NodeTop<T>{
    private Node<T> top;
    private NodeTop<T> next;
    NodeTop(Node top){
        this.top = top;
    }
}
public void push(T data){
        if(count > i){
            System.out.println("Starting new row of plates");
            NodeTop temp = new NodeTop(top);
            temp.next = nodeTop;
            nodeTop = temp;
            top = null;
            i = i + 3;
        }
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        temp.next = top;
        top = temp;
        count++;
        System.out.println(data);
}

public void pop(){
    if(top == null){
        System.out.println("Current row does not contains any plates, moving to next row");
        if(nodeTop == null){
            System.out.println("No Plates left");
            return;
        }
        top = nodeTop.top;
        nodeTop = nodeTop.next;
        i = i - 3;
    }
    System.out.println(top.data);
    top = top.next;
    count--;
}
```

}